# Spring Data Mongo: How to filtering documents by optional attributes?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb

A few Documents that already stored in Mongo db:

```
{
"companyName": "Google",
"departmentName": "Sales"
},
{
"companyName": "Google",
"departmentName": "HR"
},
{
"companyName": "Amazon",
"departmentName": "Marketing"
}
```

I need to implement a method that will receive 2 attributes: `companyName`, `departmentName` (**one of them can be optional**) and will return a list of found documents, for example:

when `departmentName` is `null` and `companyName` is `Google` method returns 2 documents:

```
{
"companyName": "Google",
"departmentName": "Sales"
},
{
"companyName": "Google",
"departmentName": "HR"
}
```

when `companyName` is `null` and `departmentName` is `Marketing` only one Document returned:

```
 {
"companyName": "Amazon",
"departmentName": "Marketing"
}
```

I tried to implement it in various ways, but no one fits my needs:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Company, String> {

  Flux<Company> findByCompanyNameAndDepartmentName(String companyName, String departmentName);

}
```

returns 0 results, when `companyName` or `departmentName` is `null`.

Option 2:

```
Company company = Company.builder()
    .companyName(null)
    .departmentName("Marketing")
    .build();

repository.findAll(Example.of(company))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

is also prints 0 results, but I expect to see one document.

so, please advice for to implement proper search?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try with the below repository interface:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Company, String> {

  Flux<Company> findByCompanyNameOrDepartmentName(String companyName, String departmentName);

}
```

Change is JPA method name change from *findByCompanyNameAndDepartmentName* to *findByCompanyNameOrDepartmentName*. Since you need the result if any one of the field matches your input.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: findByCompanyNameOrDepartmentName("Google", "Marketing") how many rows will be returned? I expect to see 0 rows because Google company doesn't have a Marketing department in my DB, but the method will return 3 documents.